# Meteor call method use the return value

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Can somebody tell me how can I use the result I receive from post.get meteor method in my react component?lets say I want to set state to result and then to render it.I tried to bind Meteor.call to this or assign it to a variable ,nothing works..
This is my task:

1.In componentDidMount make a Meteor.call to ‘post.get’ and retrieve the post

The result is an array with an object inside it.

```
export default class PostEdit extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Meteor.call("post.get", route.current().params._id, function(
      error,
      result
    ) {
      if (error) {
        alert(error);
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RenderEditPost />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My method

```
Meteor.methods({
  "post.get": function(_id) {
    return Posts.find({ _id: _id }).fetch();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
export default class PostEdit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { data: [] }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   const self = this;
    Meteor.call("post.get", route.current().params._id, function(
      error,
      result
    ) {
      if (error) {
        alert(error);
      } else {
//use arrow functions to use this.setState
        self.setState({data: result});
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RenderEditPost data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked,but can you explain me why we had to set the this ?who is self=this referring to?Please explain for a newbie I'm confused on what is going there.

Comment: Ok self=this is referring to PostEdit,but why it is not working directly with this.setState because this is referring to PostEdit too.

Comment: when you inside Meteor.call callback function we are inside the scope of that callback to access PostEdit scope we have to declare variable which refer to PostEdit so we can access inside callback